# Jquery Removed field is still available in code directly afterwards

Tags: jquery, dom

I have several Input-Boxes that are not present on first page load. They are created by JQuery via .clone().

```
<input type="text" class="myInputs" name="input[0]" />
<input type="text" class="myInputs" name="input[1]" />
<input id="remove" type="button" value="Remove last input">
```

Then I've a function to sum up all these fields and make an alert with the result, which is called by
a) an onchange function for the input fields (works like a charm) and 
b) a "remove one of the input fields"-button that should remove one field and then call the function again.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    function calculatesum() {
        var sum = 0;
        var value = 0;
        var error = false;
        var count = new Number($("input.myInputs").length);

        if(count >= 1) {
            $("input.myInputs").each(function() {
                if($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
                    value = new Number($(this).val());
                    sum = sum + value;
                }
                else
                    error = true;
            });
        }
        if(!error)  alert(sum);
        else        alert("Error");
    }

    $('body').on('change', 'input.myInputs', function () {  
        calculatesum();
    });

    $('#remove').click(function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {                 
            $('.myInputs:last').slideUp('slow', function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            calculatesum();
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Now the point is, after removing the element via the button-function, it still gets the (previously deleted) input field and its value.
How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of click at the below code fragment, like this

```
$('#remove').on('click', function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {                 
            $('.myInputs:last').slideUp('slow').remove();
            calculatesum();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Changed it. And found the error. By using $('.myInputs:last').slideUp('slow').remove();, it works.

Comment: that should work as well.Let me update my answer with your sugestion to help future visitors